# Conditional set in Zimpl?

Tags: scip

I want to do this in Zimpl, but I get the following error after I run zimpl test.zpl:

`set A := { 1..6 };
set B := { 1..4 };
set dim[A] := <1> {1}, <2> {1}, <3> {3}, <4> {2}, <5> {1}, <6> {4};
set C := {<i, j> in A*B with j<dim[i]};`

Error 800: File test.zpl Line 4 : syntax error, unexpected SETSYM

set C := { in A*B with j < dim[i]};

Basically I want these elements from `A*B: 
{<1,1>,<2,1>,<3,1>,<3,2>,<3,3>,<4,1>,<4,2>,<5,1>,<6,1>,<6,2>,<6,3>,<6,4>}`

Any idea why this is happening and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `dim` as a parameter instead of a set. Your example should look like:

```
set A := { 1..6 };
set B := { 1..4 };
param dim[A] := <1> 1, <2> 1, <3> 3, <4> 2, <5> 1, <6> 4;
set C := {<i, j> in A*B with j < dim[i]};
do print C;
```